# Can't animate graph position

Tags: mpandroidchart, ios-charts

I implemented ios-charts on a swift application I am working on and composed a graph to show some information. The graph has set setVisibleXRangeMaximum(9.0) but has more than 30 values, so the user can scroll on the graph.

I could center the selected bar on the screen when the user tap on some of the graph bars, but I can't animate it. I am using moveViewToX() method to move to an specific index. Is there a way to do the same as "moveViewToX()" does but animated?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you should ask this kind of issues on github. Only the author knows.

Comment: you should also take a look at how ChartsDemo implement the animation, and try some your ideas, and take a look at `ChartAnimator`. I guess there is a way to do it. First try add the animator, and then try moveViewToX to see if it handle the animation automatically.